# How to get count of second level hasMany relation through first level of hasMAny in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a relationship as `building` hasMany `floors` and `floor` hasMany `units`.
And I want to get the count of units per building.

I could easily obtain the count of the floor as:

```
$building = Building::findOrFail($id);
$building->floors()->count();
```

However, I could not obtain the count of units as:

```
$building = Building::findOrFail($id);
$building->floors()->units()->count();
```

My eloquent relationships are as follows:

```
Building
--------
    public function floors()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Floor');
    }
```

```
Floor
--------
    public function units()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Unit');
    }
```

All I want is to get the count of units as per the building .

Comment: You probably need a `hasManyThrough()` between `Building` and `Units`, otherwise you'd need to loop over `floors()`, as `floors()->units()` doesn't make logical sense. `$floor->units()` would (a single `Floor` instance), but `floors()->units()`, being a `Collection` of `Floor` instances doesn't allow direct access to `units()`, as it wouldn't know which one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this function in Building Model:

```
    public function units()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Unit', 'App\Models\Floor');
    }
```

Then you can easily do :

```
$building->units()->count();
```

Comment: what if I need to get count from third level relationship. Lets say, from Colony. As 1 Colony hasMany Building, Building hasMany Floor, Floor hasMany Units. So, how can I get this count from colony model?

Comment: Then you may use this package :
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep